# What is the .utmp folder in a unity project for?

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control

After creating an Android debug build of my Unity project, a new .utmp folder showed up.
It seems to contain CMake related files, but I was surprised to find absolutely no information about it. It is not mentioned in any .gitignore files for Unity and no documentation, yet it shows up even in a fresh and empty project.

My main question is if it is safe to be deleted or should I keep it on disk and ignore in git?
Secondarily I'm also curious about its purpose.

Comment: Hey, which operating system are you using?

Comment: @KBaker Windows 10 (22H2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using (Windows 10) and the .utmp folder and about 150 files were generated when I created an APK file for Samsung (Android) using a USB cable. It looks like temporary build data. I ignored the entire folder in my .gitignore using

```
/.utmp/*
```

It indeed contains CMake which is a cross-platform software tool for managing the build process. Should be safe to delete but just putting it in the git ignore is probably easier. I also wonder why the [git ignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore) from Unity doesn't have it.